# Mac OS Desktop coordinate problem

Tags: macos, mouse, coordinates

I'm having a hard time working with Mac OS screen coordinates.

I can us cmd-shift-4 to get them, but each of my monitors does not have a unique coordinate system??!?

---

[Edit: Clarification]

I have a desktop of 4 screens arranged in a 2x2 pattern.  Each screen has a size of (2048 pixels x 1152 pixels).

cmd-shift-4 gives the upper-left of each screen as (0,0) and the lower right as (2048,1152).

But each screen does that!

Technically, the coordinate system "should" run from (0,0) to (4096,2304).  How do I differentiate the coordinates of the individual monitors?

Furthermore, when I create a window at (500,500) it creates it in the top-left monitor at (500,652)

So I just don't understand what's going on.  How can I get an accurate coordinate map for the Mac OS desktop with multiple monitors?

Thanks,

Comment: By applying your elementary school math skills? -- Seriously though, if your screens have exotic relative positions, you can try to take a full screen shot and get the coordinates from the resulting picture.

Comment: I don't understand your question. You say that "each monitor goes from 0,0" but the implied "but not to…" is missing. What's "totalDesktopWidth"? Is that a variable is a program you're writing? As an aside: of course your screen isn't going to have a total width of 0…

Comment: @msanford, I've clarified my question.  Sorry.

Comment: @Daniel, I've clarified my question.

Comment: Desktop coordinate systems are different between operating systems and runtimes (e.g. Java). The environment you create your window in starts at the bottom left. Try creating the window at (0, 1100), it will be near the top left edge. `Cmd-Shift-4` (screenshot) coordinates are completely separate and for user utility purposes. **It is not a developer tool*. They probably don't want users to wonder why a screen starts in the 1000s. There might be other tools (maybe xScope or something similar has multi-monitor support?); or calculate it yourself. `2048+500` isn't *that* much of a challenge ;-)

Comment: @Daniel, no it's not that much of a challenge.  But I'm receiving coordinates from (0,0) to (1,1) (floats) from an ancillary device I'm using to control my mouse.  I need to translate those coordinates for *any* monitor size a potential user might have.  How can I access the coordinate values for the entire mac os desktop so I can convert?

Comment: Note that it makes some sense to have screenshot utilities mirror the popular pixel editor coordinate system, which starts at the top left.

Comment: You can try creating a screenshot area selection rectangle from the top left screen's top left edge to the opposite edge of the bottom right screen. It should give you the total width and height. If you want to access these properties programmatically, I suggest you post this question over on Stack Overflow.